# Using Classiq for Grover Search

Tags: grovers-algorithm

I am participating Classiq Bootcamp, [First lesson here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByADhIk42vw), and I need to implement Grover Search in a specific result that satisfies [few constrains](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfutepbBo0gw27BYG8xopGrQDnfW5qUXu6fHHxVN566WqP3bg/viewform):

1. The circuit should encompass a minimum of two Grover iterations.
2. The oracle must incorporate at least two variables.
3. In the obtained measurement results, precisely four unique bitstrings should be observed with a frequency of at least 20%. All other bitstrings should appear with a frequency of less than 5%.

I see that I have to choose a number of iterations, is this the number of Grover Iterations? Should I calculate it according to the expression I choose?

[image]